# Экранирование символов в строке пути к файлу в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

При создании графического приложения при открытии файла получаю абсолютный путь до него. Далее мне нужно получить путь до директории, где расположен файл. Тут и возникает проблема, так как он отображается не верно из-за то, что название директории начинается с числа (14C).

```
import os
path = 'C:\programs\spectra\14C\sp1.001' # получаем путь при открытии файла
dirname = os.path.dirname(path)
total = {}
total['dirname'] = dirname
print(total)
```

При запуске получаю следующее:

{'dirname': 'C:\programs\spectra\x0cC'}

А должно быть:

{'dirname': 'C:\programs\spectra\14C'}

На всякий случай скажу, что поставить символ "r" в начале строки я не могу, так как путь получаю при открытии файла.

Comment: Как вы получаете путь к файлу?

Comment: Делаю приложение  при помощи библиотеки PyQt5. В самом приложении есть виджет, в котором реализовано отображение древовидной структуры файлов. По идее при двойном нажатии на файл с определенным расширением должна выводится информация о нем. Проблема в том, что информация содержится не только в самом файле, но и в общем файле, который содержится в той же директории. Поэтому мне и нужно получить путь до этой директории, но он отображается некорректно.

Comment: Опубликуйте приложение  PyQt5, напишите что там не так. Попробуем разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, в файле fnames.txt есть строка:

```
c:\abc\14\x0x0\filename.ext
```

Тогда:

```
import os

with open('fnames.txt', 'rb') as f: # открывайте файл в режиме бинарного чтения
    fname = f.readline().decode('utf-8')
print(fname)
dirname = os.path.dirname(fname)
total = {}
total['dirname'] = dirname
print(total)
print(total['dirname'])
```

Получаем:

```
c:\abc\14\x0x0\filename.ext
{'dirname': 'c:\\abc\\14\\x0x0'}
c:\abc\14\x0x0
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработает, так как строка с адресом у меня находится в переменной, а не в текстовом файле. Записать правильно строку в текстовый файл также не получается.

Comment: @Vladimir а откуда вы получаете значение в переменную?